# Generating animated SVG with python

Tags: python, svg, slice, animated

I have been using the svgwrite library to generate a sequence of svg images. I would like to turn this sequence of images into an animated svg. The support for animated svg in svgwrite seems to only work in the form of algorithmically moving objects in the drawing. Is it possible to use the time slices I have to generate an animated svg or am I stuck rasterizing them and creating a video from the images. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The support for animated svg in svgwrite seems to only work in the form of algorithmically moving objects in the drawing.

Well, yes. That's how SVG animation works; it takes the current objects in the image and applies transformations to them. If you want a "movie" then you will need to make a video from the images.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks.